# Login into Google Account using Selenium

Tags: selenium, authentication, automation, selenium-chromedriver, google-account

A month ago I was able to login into Google Account using Selenium Webdriver.
However, something changed and everytime I start a new Chrome Session, when I try to login into any Google Account; I see this verification "captcha" text window:

["Type the text you hear or see" verification box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxrnG.png)

Does anyone know how to bypass or remove this Google Verification?

Thanks

Comment: What you are seeing is a captcha security, deployed in all probability, to prevent bots from accessing the website.  I am sure there must be Google API for docs. Research for it and use it instead. It is a more reliable way than using Selenium on any of the Google websites.

Comment: @Beto Hiro - Did you find any solution for this ?

Comment: Yes, at the company, we use a security software called ZScaller; when I disabled it, it started working.